# List of Magento XML Layout Tags

Tags: layout, xml

I have search google, loads, but with no joy. I am thinking this doesn't exist on the internet, or (more likely) I just don't know the right search terms to find this, so I apologize in advance if this seems like a fairly basic question.

I am just looking for a list of XML Layout tags. I know a few already, and I also know that you (or 3rd parties) can create and define your own custom tags. All I need is a list of the basic layout tags that Magento uses, tags like these:

```
<default>
<catalog_category_layered>
<catalog_category_default>
<cms_page>
<cms_index_index>
```

Etc.

Can anyone provide me for a more complete list?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading Alan Storm's No Frills Layout: http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout

Answer (score 4):

To see the handles for the current page (as they are different for different pages) you can add the following code at the end of the index.php file:

`var_dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());`